# Exact solution of third order non-linear ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anybody help me to find the exact solution of this problem?

\begin{eqnarray}
2y^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)+y(x)y^{\prime\prime}(x)&=&0\\
z^{\prime\prime}(x)+5y(x)z^\prime(x)&=&0
\end{eqnarray}

where boundary conditions are

$$y=0,\, y^\prime=1 \text{ and } z=1 \text{ at }x=0$$
and $y\to\infty$ and $z\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Are you certain this has an exact solution?

Comment: Wolframalpha cannot even solve the first equation. Also, you need more boundary conditions to get a unique solution

Comment: You, of course, can solve the second equation for $z(x)$, you name $z'(x)=g(x)$, thus $g'(x)=-5y(x)g(x)$, so $g(x)=c_{1}\exp\Big(-5\int^{x}y(w)dw\Big)$, so that $z(x)=c_{1}\int^{x}\exp\Big(-5\int^{v}y(w)dw\Big)dv+c_{2}$

Comment: somebody asked me to give exact solution by using symmetries. If it doesn't possess exact solution then i have to tell him how it doesn't exist.

Comment: please help me out

Comment: You can divide 1st equation by $y''$ and substitute for $y$ from 2nd. this can be integrate once to give $y''^{10}=Az'$. Maybe that helps but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are not enough boundary solutions, they are many solutions. In general, those solutions are not known on closed form. But among them, it is possible to find a solution on closed form, as shown below.

$$2y^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)+y(x)y^{\prime\prime}(x)=0 $$

$y=x$ is an obvious solution which agrees with the conditions  $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Putting it into the second equation :

$$z^{\prime\prime}(x)+5x z^\prime(x)=0$$
leads to :
$$\frac{z^{\prime\prime}(x)}{z^\prime(x)}=-5x \quad\to\quad z^\prime(x)=c_1\:e^{-\frac{5}{2}x^2}\quad\to\quad z(x)=c_1\int e^{-\frac{5}{2}x^2}dx$$
This integral involves the function erf$(x)$ :
$$z(x)=c_1\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{10}}\left(\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\:x \right)+c_2\right)$$ 
The condition $z(x=\infty)=0$ determines $c_2$  :
$$z(x)=c_1\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{10}}\:\left(\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\:x \right)-1 \right)$$
The condition $z(0)=1$ determines $c_1$  :
$$z(x)=1-\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\:x \right) $$
Finally, a solution of the problem (with incomplete wording) is :
$$\begin{cases}
y(x)=x\\
z(x)=1-\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\:x \right) 
\end{cases}$$